# Как расположить два квадрата в один ряд без отступа?

Tags: html, css

Есть два квадрата: один черный, другой красный:
Когда я вывожу на страницу два квадрата:

```css
#black {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #000;
}

#red {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: ##FF0000;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="black"></div>
  <div id="red"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

то они естественно располагаются друг под другом (черный, а под ним красный), а мне надо их расположить друг за другом.

Как решить это?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
#black {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #000;
  float: left;
}

#red {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: ##FF0000;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;">
  <div id="black">Первый блок</div>
  <div id="red">Второй блок</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

добавить:

```
#black, #red {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: #black, #red {
    display:inline-block;
}  
если так делать,то остаются зазоры между блоками

Comment: а так? #black, #red {
    display:inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

Comment: При таком подходе надо убрать все пробелы (табуляции, переводы строк...) между закрывающим и открывающим тегами.

Comment: display:inline-block; - а что это даёт? Почему это лучше чем float?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с `display: table;`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}
.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: table-cell;
}
.blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```